# Oracle imp crashes without error

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g, export, import

I have Oracle 10g XE database locally. I export schema with something like

```
exp %USER%/%PASSWD%@XE statistics=NONE owner=%USER% file=dump.dmp
```

Exp is 10.2.0.1.0 version - so is the DB.

Than I take this dump to another machine and try to import it to another remote machine. With

```
imp %USER%/%PASSWD%/'192.168.0.100/%SID%' ignore=y file=dump.dmp full=y
```

Oracle client with imp is version 11.2.0.1.0 and Oracle DB (normal, not express) is version 11.2.0.2.0

The problem is that after printing several messages about importing tables it suddenly stops:

```
. . importing table                      "TABLE_1"      17180 rows imported
. . importing table                      "TABLE_2"          0 rows imported
. . importing table                      "TABLE_3"         49 rows imported$:
```

and does not even give a newline symbol in the end.

The problem persists with rows=N and with only selected tables from this schema.

So can anybody tell:

1. Where can be some error logs to know what is wrong?
2. Some workaround (still using exp/imp utilities preferably) - we need to import dumps regularly (it is for continuous integration server), we need to do it from remote host (so impdp is hardly an option with need to mount so remote volumes), dependency on other DB is highly undesirable (dblink).

***UPD: Unfortunately for all curious we have solved the problem switching continuous integration system to Oracle XE, where is no such problem. Sysadm has already switched off this server, so I cannot try anything. Sorry.***

Comment: Can you `strace` it and paste the final output?

Answer (score 3):

1. Maybe an error appears in the target database's alert log?  Run this:

   ```
   SQL> show parameter background_dump_dest
   ```

   ...and go to the directory given to check the `alert_<SID>.log`.  Or do a trace of the imp session in the target database instance.  (Usually the errors appear in the exp / imp output themselves (saved to a log with `LOG=log_file.log` ) but I assume the export ran file with no warnings and completes with):

   ```
   "Export terminated successfully without warnings."
   ```

   When you are copying the file, are you sure it's not getting corrupted somehow? (md5sum remains the same)
2. Did you try importing into an empty schema so you don't have to set `IGNORE=Y`? 
   And when you wrote:

   > The problem persists with rows=N and *with only selected tables* from this schema.

Did you mean no matter which one or two tables you choose, it still crashes?
Try simulating an import with [SHOW=Y](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#autoId48)?

Answer (score -3):

Try copying `imp.exe` from the machine with XE to the machine with SE.

(I had this issue on my virtual test machine with Oracle Standard One 11.2.0.1.0. Imp.exe stops without messages, but in another installation with oracle 11 XE, imp.exe works fine with the same dump file. So I copied the imp.exe file of Oracle XE to the machine with Oracle Standard (replaced imp.exe), and now it's working. Maybe there's a bug in imp.exe of standard one for win32 installation...)